# Getting error 'Capture Page Screenshot' while operating multiple windows in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am Performing operations on 3 windows in robot framework*emphasized text*, getting this error after closing 2nd window.

> Error:  [ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on
>   failure: NoSuchWindowException: Message: Window not found. The browser
>   window may have been closed

Comment: Please show the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try using a keyword to select which window you want to take a screenshot of before doing so.

Like so:

```
 select window | title=calendar
```

Hope this helepd

Comment: @Supriya Katpale- Can you give more information on your excisting code?